# Square root of a square root

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Calculate square root of:

```
Sqrt[3]  Sqrt[3 - Sqrt[5]] (Sqrt[15/2] + Sqrt[3/2])
```

The response of the square root is 6.

Edit:

Can anyone go?
http://prntscr.com/aj7cnm

Comment: Did you mean `Sqrt` when you wrote `sqrt` (with a lowercase)? Also, what do you need exactly? A numerical approximation (use the `N` function for that) or a simplification of the expression?

Comment: I am Brazilian, it is difficult to express myself.
But I want you enxerguem roots in Sqrt both tiny as uppercase.
I need to solve this equation, I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: There is no equation to solve in your question. There is only an incorrect expression.

Comment: That's fine, English is not my first language either... But I need to understand: You are considering this expression: `Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[3 - Sqrt[5]]*Sqrt[15/2] + Sqrt[3/2]` correct?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/aj4kt6 My expression.

Comment: You have it correct except you need to enclose the last two terms in parenthesis. `Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[3 - Sqrt[5]]*(Sqrt[15/2] + Sqrt[3/2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand the question, but here are some thoughts. Hopefully this will get us closer to the problem you are trying to solve:

```
expr = Sqrt[3] * Sqrt[3 - Sqrt[5]] * (Sqrt[15/2] + Sqrt[3/2])
```

Get the numerical value:

```
N[expr] (* gives 6. *)
```

Simplify the expression:

```
FullSimplify[expr] (* gives 6 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Compared to the picture in your link, your expression is missing parentheses. Your expression should read

```
expr = Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[3 - Sqrt[5]]*(Sqrt[15/2] + Sqrt[3/2]);

expr // FullSimplify

(*  6  *)
```